# Problema ao excluir um registro, buscar o próximo

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-core

Estou tentando fazer no código, uma página editar, então o usuário nesta página de editar, ele pode excluir o registro, e se ele excluir, o sistema tem que verificar, se existir um registro próximo, ele vai para tela de editar do próximo, se não existe o id próximo, ele tenta o registro anterior, e caso não tenha nem o próximo, nem o anterior, ele retorna para a página de incluir um novo.
Segue a lógica que estou fazendo, mas nem sempre funciona.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ExcluirProduto(int id)
    {
        var result = false;
        var item = db.Produtos.Find(id);

        if (item != null)
        {
            db.Produtos.Remove(item);
            db.SaveChanges();

            result = true;
        }
        var itemProx = db.Produtos.Where(e => e.Id >= id).OrderBy(e => e.Id).Skip(1).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
        var itemAnte = db.Produtos.Where(e => e.Id <= id).OrderByDescending(e => e.Id).Skip(1).Take(1).FirstOrDefault();
        int idprox = 0;
        int idant = 0;
        try
        {
            idprox = itemProx.Id;
        }
        catch { idprox = 0; }
        try
        {
            idant = itemAnte.Id;
        }
        catch { idant = 0; }
        try
        {
            if (idprox == 0 && idant == 0)
            {
                id = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                if (idprox != 0)
                {
                    id = (itemProx.Id);

                }
                else
                {
                    id = (itemAnte.Id);
                }
            }
            return Json(new { Resultado = result, id });
        }
        catch {
            id = 0;
            return Json(new { Resultado = result, id });
        }
    }
```

E aqui é o meu AJAX que redireciona a página:

```
 function Excluir(idproduto) {
    var idproduto = document.getElementById("Id").value;
    var url = "/Produto/ExcluirProduto";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: { id: idproduto },
        datatype: "json",
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.resultado) {
                alert('Excluído com sucesso.');
                if (data.id != 0) {
                    window.location.href = "/Produto/Editar/" + (data.id);
                }
                else {
                    window.location.href = "/Produto/Novo";
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Lembrando que utilizo MVC Core - Page Razor.

Comment: Quando não funciona?

Comment: Quando eu vou excluindo vários de uma vez, e mesmo havendo registros próximos ou anteriores, ele retorna para a página novo.

Comment: Falta detalhes do que está errado a pergunta está longa. Tente editá-la para conseguir respostas úteis.
Como contribuição, utilize `console.log` no data.resultado para verificar, provavavelmente está vindo um valor negativo (undefined, 0, null, "", etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sua lógica de seleção está um pouco confusa na sua `Controller` e pode ser simplificada. E alterei o seu objeto de retorno `Json` para garantir que ele apresente o formato de propriedade e valor e respeite o case.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ExcluirProduto(int id)
{   
    var result = false;
    var item = db.Produtos.Find(id);

    if (item != null)
    {
        db.Produtos.Remove(item);
        db.SaveChanges();

        result = true;
    }
    //Seleciona o próximo maior
    int? proximoProdutoId = db.Produtos.Select(p => p.Id)
                                        .OrderBy(p => p)
                                        .FirstOrDefault(p => p > id);

    //Se for 0, tenta selecionar o próximo menor
    if(proximoProdutoId == 0)
        proximoProdutoId = db.Produtos.Select(p => p.Id)
                                      .OrderByDescending(p => p)
                                      .FirstOrDefault(p => p < id);


    return Json(new { resultado = result, id = proximoProduto});
}
```

Com esses ajustes o seu javascript deve se comportar da forma correta, mas vale observar que da forma como escreveu, se o `id` de entrada não existir no contexto para ser excluído, o `resultado` será `false` e nada acontecerá na página.

Comment: Ele ta retornando o seguinte erro: O operador "??" não pode ser aplicado a operandos dos tipos "int" e "int". 
E no returnJson, id = proximoProdutoId.

Comment: @marianac_costa, Ajustado

Comment: Fiz os testes, e o problema não ocorreu mais, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Vejo dois erros a serem corrigidos na sua lógica:

1. Você não precisa usar o ".Skip(1).Take(1)", pois o comando FirstOrDefault precedido pelo OrderBy/OrderByDescending já resolve a questão de pegar o próximo ou o anterior.
2. Na sua chamada Ajax, se o data.resultado for 'falso', sua aplicação não vai fazer nada.

Você não deixou claro o real problema, mas talvez tenha a ver com estas duas situações.

Comment: Fiz o teste retirando o skip e o take, e nada acontece. Fiz desta forma, pois vi em uma reposta aqui no fórum que funcionava. Em questão do ajax for falso não fazer nada, é assim mesmo que deve ser.